# Solving 1 equation with 2 variables in php

Tags: php, variables, math, equation

I am trying to find the solution of `a^10-b^15 = 10510100501`

Is there a way to find it?

I wrote the following code in PHP but with no result:

```
<?php
    $total = 0;
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
    for($b=0;$b<10000;$b++){
        for($a=0;$a<10000;$a++){
            $total = pow($a,10) - pow($b,15);

            if($total == 10510100501){ echo $a." ".$b; }
            if($total > 10510100501){ continue;}
        }
    }
    echo "none";
?>
```

Comment: you don't appear to be taking precision into account...

Comment: isn't it more about maths than about PHP?

Comment: is there a condition that `a` and `b` must be positive integers?

Comment: you need two equations to solve this otherwise it's just brute force guessing

Comment: a and be should be integers

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run this code , the loop will iterate upto 10 Million times . It exceeds max execution time of PHP ... 
   So, Result will be unknown (Time out)..

The particular output may not be achieved as you are looping through integer values only..

To get that particular value you should try with float values.

Comment: The riddle indicate that the value of a and b should be integers , yes you are right the code executes for a and b < 8000 , but still no result

Answer (score -1):

instead of second if you should use else only.

```
 <?php
    $total = 0;
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
    for($b=0;$b<10000;$b++){
        for($a=0;$a<10000;$a++){
            $total = pow($a,10) - pow($b,15);

            if($total == 10510100501){ echo $a." ".$b; }
            else { continue;}
        }
    }
    echo "none";
?>
```

Comment: this can't work because it will it will skip the a for loop at the first iteration !